# mencoder generate mp4 h.264 from jpg playback stops in html videotag chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jpeg, mencoder

So I have some images from which I create a video with mencoder.

```
mencoder -idx -nosound -noskip -of lavf -lavfopts format=mp4 -ovc x264 -x264encopts pass=1:bitrate=2000:crf=24 -o output.mp4 -mf fps=15 'mf://@files.txt'
```

(where files.txt is a list of all the files sorted in the right order)

The videos is created without problems, it plays fine in desktop-player like vlc, but in chrome (on mac) and chromium (ubuntu) some of the videoes has *"breakpoints"* in which the video just stops.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAk7P/1/).

I made an ugly hack ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAk7P/2/)) to force a continued play even if the video is damaged, but this does not look very nice when the video has a lot of them *"breakpoints"*.

For several reasons I need to be using html, so flash would only be a **last** last resort.
Any views on what may be causing these breakpoints? Or a nicer ugly hack to force contiuned playback?

Comment: Well after trying a different path to fix it, turned out bframes seems to be what was causing it.. MEncoder's libavformat muxing is currently broken, so by editing the command a bit to disable bframes made some testvideos work.

`mencoder -idx -nosound -noskip -of lavf -lavfopts format=mp4 -ovc x264 -x264encopts pass=1:bitrate=2000:bframes=0:crf=24 -o output.mp4 -mf fps=15 'mf://@files.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

try adding `-vf harddup -ofps 15` to duplicate many frames and set the output FPS to a good value, like 15 in your case